# passing multiple fileds for ajax validation with jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jquery validation engine to validate form input.  It works fine.
I have a situation where I'm asking the user for a country and postcode and I need to validate that the combination of country and postcode is valid.

The code to validate the field individually works fine and looks like this:

```
<p class="mediumlargefont add_margin_top">Please confirm your country:</p>
<input onclick="$('#postcode').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Please select your country', 'load')"
    class="validate[required, custom[onlyLetterSp], maxSize[30], ajax[ajaxNameCallCountry]]" 
    type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete" value="[% IF country; country; END %]"/>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="mediumlargefont add_margin_top">Please enter your postcode:</p>
    <input maxlength="10" size="22"  
    onclick="$('#postcode').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Please enter the postcode of your current location', 'load')"
    class="validate[condRequired[country], custom[onlyLetterNumberSpHy], maxSize[10], ajax[ajaxNameCallPostcode]]" 
    type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" data-prompt-position="centerRight"/>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to know is, is there a way, when I validate the postcode, to also pass the current value of the country input with the ajax call to the backend? That would allow me to validate the combination.

BTW, the JS for validation engine looks like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#postcodeForm").validationEngine('attach', 'autoHidePrompt', {
        scroll: "false",
        ajaxFormValidation : "true"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, 10 minutes later I found the answer.  Hope it helps someone else.

Within the definition for the ajax selector you add extraDataDynamic

For example,

```
"ajaxUserCall": {
    "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
    "extraData": "name=eric",
    "extraDataDynamic": ['#user_id', '#user_email'],
    "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
    "alertTextOk": "All good!",
    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
},
```